# Is there a way to store an arithmetic operator in a variable and use the variable itself within a calculation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, operators, arithmetic-expressions

Using the following 3 variables - I wanted to calculate two numbers with whatever the operator variable was set to. For example -> num1 * num2..

```
const num1 = 10;
const num2 = 4;
const operator = `*`; //Could be any arithmetic operator
```

I know this can be done using an if or switch statement, but I'm curious to know if there is a way to do it in less lines of code using the operation variable itself in the actual calculation.

I tried out the following things (I mostly expected them to turn out the way they did):

```
console.log(num1 + operation + num2);    //Outputs: "10*4"

console.log(num1, operation, num2);    //Outputs: 10 "*" 4

console.log(`${num1} ${operation} ${num2}`);    //Outputs: "10 * 4"

console.log(num1 operation num2);    //Outputs: Error

const calculation = num1 operation num2; console.log(calculation);    //Outputs: Error

console.log(1 + operation + 2);    //Outputs: "1*2"

console.log(Number(1 + operation + 2));    //Outputs: NaN
```

So is there something I haven't tried yet that would make this work, or can it just not be done like this?

Comment: There's no direct way to do that in JavaScript. In Lisp-like languages, the "operators" are functions, so you can achieve what you're attempting. You could of course make your own set of functions as properties of an object.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an object with the wanted operators, test if the operator exist, and use it.

```js
var operators = {
        '+': (a, b) => a + b,
        '-': (a, b) => a - b,
        '*': (a, b) => a * b,
        '/': (a, b) => a / b
    },
    calculate = function (val1, val2, sign) {
        if (sign in operators) {
            return operators[sign](val1, val2);
        }
    }

console.log(calculate(6, 7, '*'));
```